# Grab top level json element with jq

Tags: json, jq, okta-api

I can grab sub elements without an issue, but if i try top level element it fails, i was wondering if anyone knew the best way to grab the value for the ID element

This works to grab sub elements

```
AUTHENTICATOR_NAME=$(echo "$RESPONSE2" | jq '.[] | .profile.authenticatorName')
```

This does not work for grabbing the value of "id" at a higher level, it returns "jq: error (at :1): Cannot index array with string "id"

```
FACTOR_ID=$(echo "$RESPONSE2" | jq -r '.id')


    [
    {
        "id": "xxxxxxxxxxx1111111111",
        "factorType": "webauthn",
        "provider": "FIDO",
        "vendorName": "FIDO",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "created": "2024-01-31T19:38:50.000Z",
        "lastVerified": "2024-02-27T13:28:19.000Z",
        "lastUpdated": "2024-01-31T19:38:50.000Z",
        "profile": {
            "credentialId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "appId": null,
            "version": null,
            "authenticatorName": "YubiKey 5",
            "presetPinAvailable": null,
            "fulfillmentProvider": null
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is explicit: you're trying to use `"id"` to access an element of an array.

In the first case you use `'.[] | .profile.authenticatorName'` which is equivalent to "map each element of the array to its sub property '.profile.authenticatorName'"

In the second case you use `'.id'` which is "extract the 'id' property from the input".

What you probably meant to use is **`'.[] | .id'`** which is "map each element of the array to its property 'id'"

Comment: Note that the shorter `.[].profile.authenticatorName` and `.[].id` could have been used (in the same way that `.profile.authenticatorName` was used instead of `.profile | .authenticatorName`).

Comment: True! I just don't use jq that often to remember its syntax